# My Django web app isn't functioning properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new at Django and I've been making a login and registration form using bootstrap and then connecting the bootstrap template with Django. The form has a sign in and sign-up page which has a smooth transition when you click on each of them. But when I click on the sign-up, nothings happening.I've set up the static files and the website is displaying correctly although not functioning correctly. Can someone help me resolve this problem?
I've provided the CSS file here https://easyupload.io/gq48hs.
The login and registration page looks like this https://ibb.co/jr4pm3N
Bootstrap

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Online Timetable - Student Login and registration form</title>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/style.css' %}"/>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
```

## Login & registration Form

-->

### SIGN IN

### SIGN UP

USERNAME
                    

                    PASSWORD

#### Keep me signed in

---

Forgot password?
            

            
                
                    USERNAME
                    

                    E-MAIL
                      

                    PASSWORD
                    

                    CONFIRM PASSWORD

#### I agree

```
</body>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>    <script  src="{% static 'css/script.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>

$('.btn-enregistrer').click(function() {
$('.connexion').addClass('remove-section');
$('.enregistrer').removeClass('active-section');
$('.btn-enregistrer').removeClass('active');
$('.btn-connexion').addClass('active');
});

$('.btn-connexion').click(function() {
$('.connexion').removeClass('remove-section');
$('.enregistrer').addClass('active-section');   
$('.btn-enregistrer').addClass('active');
$('.btn-connexion').removeClass('active');
});
```

URLS.Py
   from django.urls import path
   from .import views

urlpatterns = [

```
path('',views.login),
```

]

```
Views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def login(request):
return render(request,'login/index.html')


URLS.Py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include



urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include('login.urls')),
]
```

Comment: The signup view would be different than the login view, so you'd need to point a signup submit to the right view, for example: `views.signup`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add {% load staticfiles %} above your script tags

```
<body>
<!-- partial -->
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>    <script  src="{% static 'css/script.js' %}"></script>

</body>
```